# I want to enable free shipping

Tags: magento2, database, event-observer

I want to enable free shipping if some condition satisfies(programmatically). Which event should I use and how should my observer look like..?

Kindly guide.

Comment: You can create cart price rule for applying free shipping with some conditions.

Comment: Yes @Ranganathan but how to do it..?!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin panel->Marketing->Cart price rules` click on `Add new` button.

Fill the required field with coupon code value as `No Coupon`.

And go to `Actions` tab create a rule that match with your requirement under

**Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items).**

Select `Free Shipping` drop down  value as `For matching items only`.

Clear the cache and check in your store.

Comment: Thanks .. But I want to do it by programmatically.